# How to detect dev and production environment in Gradle based Spring Boot 2.0.0 app?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

This question is in the context running app as war deployed to tomcat. It is not quite clear to me how can I specify parameters in application.properties or application.yml that have different values depending if the app is running in production or in dev? Like below

```
if env == dev then myparam1 = devvalue

if env == prod then myparam1 = prodvalue
```

Note that I am using Gradle and not Maven.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As refered to in the comments you could use Spring profiles for the different environments and provide separate configuration files for these profiles.

On production:

- Add a file `application-prod.yml` with the production settings.
- Start the application with option `--spring.profiles.active=prod` or environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod`.

On dev environment:

- Add a file `application-dev.yml` with the development settings.
- Start the application with option `--spring.profiles.active=dev` or environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`.

Note that you can keep some common settings suitable for all environments in your `application.yml` and only override some specific keys in the environment config files.

EDIT:

In order to activate a certain Spring profile for your application in a Tomcat servlet context you can add a context parameter with the name `spring.profiles.active` to the `<Context>` element. See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters

Comment: How do I specify --spring.profiles.active=dev or --spring.profiles.active=prod in tomcat when deploying the as war in tomcat?

Comment: @ace as always, the documentation is your friend: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config